# Is the use of "plz send teh codez" and its derivatives acceptable in Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I know that the meme *plz send teh codez* originated outside of Stack Exchange, and I know that there have been efforts to keep this out of Stack Overflow tags, but it seems to me that there is a fairly widespread acceptance of its use as a descriptive term, at least on Meta Stack Overflow.

I completely understand the need to characterize "please send me the code" questions, but it seems to me that intentionally using misspellings is unnecessarily offensive to those for whom English is a second language, no matter how frequently such questions are misspelled.

I looked at the Stack Exchange content policy and couldn't find anything that really addresses "respectfulness". There's something about not being defamatory, but I don't think that applies here.

Is there some other guideline that this might fall under?

Comment: ["Be Nice"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: I think it probably means that site policy is "Be Nice" and you're asking "Is it alright to be rude?"

Comment: My *guess* would be that those folks think this is an extremely simple question, and probably the answer seemed obvious to them. Just a guess.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar - Since I explicitly said that I think such language is offensive, it's hard for me to imagine someone thinking that I'm asking if being rude is ok. Also, since this term is so widely used on MSO, its hard for me to believe that people think the common wisdom is that this "is" rude.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Just realized that the "Be Nice" guideline is for SO, not for MSO, let alone SE. Actually, that pretty much matches my experience using SO vs. MSO. :-)

Comment: Overwhelmingly- if not exclusively- the people I have seen use 'plz', 'teh', and the letter z to indicate pluralization have been native speakers. If that were not the case, this meme wouldn't have stuck around.

Comment: The use of intentional misspellings isn't offensive, but does make it tougher for non native speakers (that is, non native to English internet slang) to grasp the meaning. The saying itself is rude because it's used in a derogatory fashion, *including here on meta*, implying that the asker isn't putting forth any effort and is lazy.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178050/is-civility-and-tolerance-not-required-on-meta-sites

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19780/56338

Comment: @EsotericScreenName: If it's derogatory because it is "implying that the asker isn't putting forth any effort and is lazy", then would that also mean "You need to try something first and come back with an example" is derogatory? because it has the same meaning (by your definition)

Comment: @sth - Thank you for the reference.

Comment: Internet slang is my native language.

Comment: @OldCheckmark I pity you.

Comment: "plz send teh codez" origin story: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/plz-email-me-teh-codez.aspx

Comment: @root - I honestly had no idea that `teh` had become Internet slang (just read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teh). That said, I'd be interested in any examples you can point to where a native speaker used "plz send teh codes" _other_ than in referring to someone else's request for code.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - After reflecting on my past experience with MSO and the comments/answers here, I'm pretty sure that most if not all of the downvotes mean that they disagree with the opinion I expressed within my question about policy. That is, they do _not_ find the meme to be offensive.

Comment: @musefan Derogatory yes, as it's critical, but it's not also rude. The definition of derogatory includes both rude and non-rude variations.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I think the downvotes are more about the content of your post i.e. the relation you seem to be suggesting between the meme and non-native English speakers.

Comment: @AsheeshR - Agreed, although given the origin (http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/plz-email-me-teh-codez.aspx) I think the relationship is pretty clear, even if those using it are unaware of it.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin that assumes we are using the term because we've read that post. I, for one, have not, and I certainly don't use the phrase with any connotation to anything except lazy, since it seems that the post implies that it is about foreign language speakers. If you choose to take offense to that, *shrug*. I don't think many other people here do. Can't please everybody.

Comment: @AsheeshR - Sorry, I did not mean to suggest that people using the term were aware of the relationship. I accept that you and others saw no relationship and were thinking of it as simply textspeak or Internet slang. When I said that the relationship was "clear", I meant only that there was a correlation, as evidenced by the origin.

Comment: No issues. I hadnt known about the origin similar to Aaron. I have seen the meme only within the context mentioned in my answer (within the SE network). The actual origin does not reflect the real usage in this case.

Comment: @programmer5000 Imho, yes. It's unnecessarily incorporating an offensive phrase when it could easily have picked something else.

Answer (score 36):

The meme isn't about English: it is about a specific category of questions which consist of absolutely no research, no effort, and simply ask for the complete solution to a problem. These types of questions generally tend to assume that Stack Overflow is a free coding service, and the meme inside of SE is used almost exclusively to refer to that.

I have never seen it being used to refer to posts by non-native speakers. You seem to be making an inaccurate connection between the meme and something entirely different.

In cases where it is used in a manner which may sound offensive to non-native speakers, especially users who may not be familiar with the meme, you should flag these comments as either *offensive* or *not constructive*. These comments are, after all, not adding anything useful to the question/discussion.

Comment: +1 - the meme is about *lazy* users, not *non-English* users.

Comment: How is this line of argument different from those who use/defend the contemporary use of certain phrases on the grounds that they're not intended to refer to the associated population and only meant to be generally derogatory? See http://www.thinkb4youspeak.com/, for example. Then there's http://mentalfloss.com/article/12503/politically-incorrect-etymologies-11-words-and-phrases, which have offensive origins that most people are unaware of. Given the various responses, I _suppose_ this could fall into the latter category, but it's really hard to believe a significant percentage aren't aware.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think context is extremely important with this as it can refer to a specific category of question, but if it is directed at a specific individual, I think it can be used to mock - not necessarily due to the command of the English language, but due to the over use of text-speak when writing online.

I despise text-speak in posts, but I think there are far more constructive ways to address the matter than by mocking a user, however this objection is more related to its usage in comments on Stack Overflow and in misdirected questions on MSO when directed as a specific user or specific post.

The usage in describing questions on MSO, I think is acceptable as it is a common meme that most everyone is familiar with.

Comment: And why shouldn't text-speak be mocked? U no u want 2.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I think there are more constructive ways to ask them to clean up the post

Comment: If I take the question correctly, he's talking about the use of the term *here on MSO*, not directed at users on the main site. There are more constructive ways to say most of the things we say; that doesn't make them all offensive.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I missed MSO in the question completely.... I've seen it used plenty of times in SO post comments and I was trying to address that.  I actually don't have an issue with its usage on Meta because more often than not, it is referring to the class of question and not a specific user

Comment: Right, here it is almost exclusively used to categorize lazy users - err, users who do lazy things - not poke fun individually.

Comment: @AaronBertrand hopefully my edit clarifies my position